# Main application and tests doesn't work due to database related errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I am trying to create tests for my Spring Boot application (I have never created tests before so this is my first time.). I use MongoDB Atlas in my main application and H2 database for my test. I have created another `application.properties` file for my test inside of the `test` directory. After I created `application.properties` file for my test and run the test, it tried to connect my MongoDB database. To prevent this that I add this line to my test `application.properties` file: `spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration`.

However, this line caused to this error: `Parameter 0 of constructor in com.aozbek.form.service.UserDetailsServiceImp required a bean named 'mongoTemplate' that could not be found.` I don't know why does this happen because in my test I didn't use anything related to `UserDetailsServiceImp` file. Here is my test file:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
class FieldRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private FieldRepository underTest;

    @Test
    void itShouldGetFormFieldById() {

        //given
        FormField formField = new FormField(
                "1",
                "School",
                "text",
                "2"
        );
        underTest.save(formField);

        //when
        Optional<FormField> searchedFormField = underTest.getFormFieldById("1");

        //then
        assertThat(searchedFormField).isPresent();
        assertThat(searchedFormField).contains(formField);

    }
}
```

And here is my `application.properties` file in the test directory:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2://mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration
```

Also, my main application was working fine before adding these `application.properties` and `FieldRepositoryTest.java` files. However, after adding all of them, I tried to run my main application to see if it works or not and I got this error:

```
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

Here is my `application.properties` file for the main application:

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=form-data-db
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://information-to-access-db
server.error.include-binding-errors=always
```

I don't understand why these two `application.properties` file can't properly work together. Besides, why do I need `'mongoTemplate'` bean to construct `UserDetailsServiceImp` for the above test. Because I don't use anything related to it in my test. In my test, I directly use `FieldRepository` without need to `UserDetailsServiceImp`. So, I have several questions to ask if you can answer, I would be very happy.

1- How can I make this test work properly?

2- Why do these `application.properties` files can't work together properly?

3- Why do I need `'mongoTemplate'` bean in this class: `UserDetailsServiceImp` in my test? (I am asking this because my test doesn't use this class at all.)

EDIT:

Here is my `FieldRepository` implementation:

```
@Repository
public interface FieldRepository extends MongoRepository<FormField, String> {
    Optional<FormField> getFormFieldById(String id);
    List<FormField> findAllByFormId(String id);
}
```

Comment: Do you try to use H2 as a drop-in replacement for the MongoDB of your application when you run the tests? Or do you want to store additional data for your tests and do not touch anything MongoDB releated while executing your tests (also not in the tested production code)?

Comment: And please add your implementation of `FieldRepository` to your question, maybe you have a transitional dependency to `UserDetailsServiceImp`.

Comment: I was trying to substitute MongoDB with an in-memory H2 database for testing purposes. And I was trying to check if this: `Optional<FormField> getFormFieldById(String id);` query method works alright. And yes I will add my `FieldRepository` in a minute and thank you for answering the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use H2 in place of MongoDB, H2 is a relational database with tables etc., and MongoDB is a document based database.

Spring has a library spring-data-mongodb for use with MongoDB and another library spring-data-jpa for use with relational databases.

You have a transitional dependency to `MongoTemplate` in your code with your `FieldRepository` because that interface extends `MongoRepository` (see it's [JavaDocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html)). The class `SimpleMongoRepository` needs an instance of `MongoOperations` in its constructor and the implementation of that is `MongoTemplate`.

If you want to do an integration test, you will have to use MongoDB - or you switch to unit tests without real database interactions.